# ANR From Google Admob Interstitial Ad

Tags: android, admob

I am getting ANR while using AdMob Interstitial Ad. Below are the ANR log

### Anr Log :

```
ANR Detected
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.cache.b.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@17121050@17.1.21 (040406-245070773):42)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.cache.a.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@17121050@17.1.21 (040406-245070773):3)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at vq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@17121050@17.1.21 (040406-245070773):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@17121050@17.1.21 (040406-245070773):8)
    at vq.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@17121050@17.1.21 (040406-245070773):4)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6760)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)


 --- Device details ---
{
  "manufacturer": "vivo",
  "model": "vivo 1724",
  "apiLevel": "27",
  "osVersion": "8.1.0",
  "deviceId": "b2d146cf9a24a044",
  "width": 720,
  "height": 1440,
  "ueSDKVersion": "V2–2-04272019-20:15:44",
  "appVersion": "2.2.4 [136]",
  "networkType": "WiFi",
  "tIntM": "9382",
  "aIntM": "2980",
  "tRAM": "2976",
  "aRAM": "1188",
  "platform": 1,
  "rv": "1.1.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/91AxN2Q9Znk

Here they say: "Our recommendation is to call [MobileAds.initialize](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds.html#initialize(android.content.Context)) early on in the app to force some of this class loading to happen sooner."

Can you check that you are doing that?